# замена active directory в linux

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, opensource

В организации используется AD и постепенно всё идёт к переходу на открытое ПО.

Встал вопрос о том чем его заменить. Что нужно от AD:

1. Аутентификация и авторизация пользователей. Создание в AD аутентификация на клиентской машине, создание групп.
2. Роль DNS сервера.
3. Сетевая шара и установка прав с использованием пользователей и групп AD.

При полном переходе на linux серверных и клиентский машин - что сможет заменить AD?

Comment: можно просто поставить ldap сервер https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/debian_ldap_install1.txt.html , вроде он умеет вышеуказанное.

Comment: [Samba as AD Controller](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller)

Comment: Присмотритесь к [ClearOS](https://www.clearos.com). Выпускается готовым дистрибутивом. Если не ошибаюсь **Community Edition** - бесплатна. Хотите, испытайте полнофункциональную версию. Плюсы - готовый к использованию продукт дешевле аналога от Microsoft. Минусы - он платен. Впрочем, я уже упомянул про существование редакции "комьюнити".Сориентируетесь по установленным пакетам, на что можете заменить сервисы Microsoft.

Comment: Вот готовый дистрибутив это конечно был бы идеальный вариант. Но платный - не вариант :(

Comment: Мы у себя тестили - всё плохо. Есть `freeipa+samba+sssd`, но если чё-то ломается в самбе - ОЧЕНЬ нетривиальная задача починить. В общем - я тебе сочувствую, готовься к боли.